# SymmetricDS missing its node_identity

Tags: symmetricds

I use symmetricds 3.8.0 to sync data between Oracle 12.1 and Mysql 5.5. Oracle is the Master Server. I use the demo properties to configure with modifying its db connection information.But when I execute command : bin/sym, there show the message below:

This node is configured as a registration server, but it is missing its node_identity.  It probably needs configured

It only occur when the master server is Oracle, nothing with Mysql and Mssql, I try it many times but it still show this issue, Do someone meet this problem and help me?

Comment: what's your symmetricds SQL configuration that is inserted in the oracle DB before starting the engine?

Comment: the SQL configuration is from demo

Comment: insert into sym_channel 
(channel_id, processing_order, max_batch_size, enabled, description)
values('sale_transaction', 1, 100000, 1, 'sale_transactional data from register and back office');

insert into sym_channel 
(channel_id, processing_order, max_batch_size, enabled, description)
values('item', 1, 100000, 1, 'Item and pricing data');

insert into sym_node_group (node_group_id) values ('corp');
insert into sym_node_group (node_group_id) values ('store');

Comment: insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('corp', 'store', 'W');
insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('store', 'corp', 'P');

Comment: insert into sym_trigger 
(trigger_id,source_table_name,channel_id,last_update_time,create_time)
values('item_selling_price','item_selling_price','item',current_timestamp,current_timestamp);

insert into sym_trigger 
(trigger_id,source_table_name,channel_id,last_update_time,create_time)
values('item','item','item',current_timestamp,current_timestamp);

insert into sym_trigger 
(trigger_id,source_table_name,channel_id,last_update_time,create_time)
values('sale_transaction','sale_transaction','sale_transaction',current_timestamp,current_timestamp);

Comment: insert into sym_trigger 
(trigger_id,source_table_name,channel_id,last_update_time,create_time)
values('sale_return_line_item','sale_return_line_item','sale_transaction',current_timestamp,current_timestamp);


insert into sym_router 
(router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
values('corp_2_store', 'corp', 'store', 'default',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

Comment: insert into sym_router 
(router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
values('store_2_corp', 'store', 'corp', 'default',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

Comment: insert into sym_trigger_router 
(trigger_id,router_id,initial_load_order,last_update_time,create_time)
values('sale_transaction','store_2_corp', 200, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

Comment: Please, add this configuration as code block to the question. Can't see the `sym_node_security` table

Comment: Who can help me ? please

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception? Add it with the configuration to your original question, not here in comments, please

Answer (score 0):

sym_node_identity table has to be populated with one row describing the identity of the root DB on oracle

Comment: Yes, I did, there are one record in the identity table, it is '000' according to the demo.But the issue still occur.